# Read a big file by lines in C++

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I have a big file nearly 800M, and I want to read it line by line.

At first I wrote my program **in Python**, I use linecache.getline:

```
lines = linecache.getlines(fname)
```

It costs about 1.2s.

Now I want to transplant my program to C++.

I wrote these code:

```
    std::ifstream DATA(fname);
    std::string line;
    vector<string> lines;

    while (std::getline(DATA, line)){
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
```

But it's slow(costs minutes). How to improve it?

- Joachim Pileborg mentioned `mmap()`, and on windows `CreateFileMapping()` will work.

---

My code runs under VS2013, when I use "DEBUG" mode, it takes `162` seconds;

When I use "RELEASE" mode, only `7` seconds!

(*Great Thanks To @DietmarKühl and @Andrew*)

Comment: You were running an optimised build of the C++ program, right?

Comment: Did you mean `linecache.getline`? There's no `linecache.getlines`.

Comment: The fist example splits the input by whitespace. Sure it's slower.

Comment: The first C++ code doesn't read *lines*, it read whitespace delimited "words".

Comment: As for the second C++ code, almost all input and output function (including `std::istream::getline`) returns the steam object, and you can use that as a boolean to see if there's an error of end of file. No need for the extra length check. And any reason to not use `std::getline`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I paste wrong code, sorry. I did use std::getline, but still slow.

Comment: Also, have you thought about memory mapping the file (full or partial), and just read character by character into a buffer until you get a newline? That would probably be the fastest way to read it.

Comment: When doing time-critical operations (such as profiling) with C++ I/O streams, it's a good idea to call [`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio).

Comment: As you are storing all lines in a vector, it takes space (and maybe this causes some swapping) and time to manage it.

Comment: @MichelBillaud I tried only read string and do nothing in while loop, still slow. I'm trying to use memory mapping.

Comment: On my laptop it is 0.1 second for a  202 Mb file in C++ (without any optimization).

Comment: @MichelBillaud can you paste you code?

Comment: It's exactly the same as in the original message, with `auto fname = "/tmp/bigfile",` and the usual includes, `main()` etc. Question: how are you compiling your file ? And running it ?

Comment: There are huge differences in how IOStreams are implemented. With libstdc++ (the library shipping with gcc) the functions are defined in the library which is built with optimization. With Dinkumware's implementation (the library shipping with MSVC++) I think the implementation is mainly still in the headers (as streams are templates) and **not** compiling with optimization has a **huge** performance impact on streams (I'm not using MSVC++, though, so I don't know if it matters). Try using an optimized ("release") build.

Comment: Complaining about the performance of a C++ program compiled without optimisations is pointless. You don't determine the fastest runner by who can read maps best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should probably make sure you are compiling with optimizations enabled.  This might not matter for such a simple algorithm, but that really depends on your vector/string library implementations.

As suggested by @angew, [std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) makes a big difference on routines like the one you have written.

Another, lesser, optimization would be to use `lines.reserve()` to preallocate your vector so that `push_back()` doesn't result in huge copy operations.  However, this is most useful if you happen to know in advance approximately how many lines you are likely to receive.

Using the optimizations suggested above, I get the following results for reading an 800MB text stream:

```
 20 seconds ## if average line length = 10 characters
  3 seconds ## if average line length = 100 characters
  1 second  ## if average line length = 1000 characters
```

As you can see, the speed is dominated by per-line overhead.  This overhead is primarily occurring inside the `std::string` class.

It is likely that any approach based on storing a large quantity of `std::string` will be suboptimal in terms of memory allocation overhead.  On a 64-bit system, `std::string` will require a *minimum* of 16 bytes of overhead per string.  In fact, it is very possible that the overhead will be significantly greater than that -- and you could find that memory allocation (inside of `std::string`) becomes a significant bottleneck.

For optimal memory use and performance, consider writing your own routine that reads the file in large blocks rather than using `getline()`.  Then you could apply something similar to the [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to manage the indexing of the individual lines using a custom string class.

P.S. Another relevant factor will be the physical disk I/O, which might or might not be bypassed by caching.

Answer (score 1):

For c++ you could try something like this:

```
void processData(string str)
{
  vector<string> arr;
  boost::split(arr, str, boost::is_any_of(" \n"));
  do_some_operation(arr);
}

int main()
{
 unsigned long long int read_bytes = 45 * 1024 *1024;
 const char* fname = "input.txt";
 ifstream fin(fname, ios::in);
 char* memblock;

 while(!fin.eof())
 {
    memblock = new char[read_bytes];
    fin.read(memblock, read_bytes);
    string str(memblock);
    processData(str);
    delete [] memblock;
 }
 return 0;
}
```